# Parsing fixed-width input using ANTLR4

Tags: antlr, antlr4, lexer

I have a strange input format along the lines of:

```
ACOMAND          1.0       1.0
ACOMAND
ACOMAND          1.0
ACOMAND          1.0       1.0    1300.2                  .9       1.0
ACOMAND          1.0       1.0    1300.2                  .9
ACOMAND          OKK       1.0    1300.2                  .9       1.0       WOW
ACOMAND          1.0       1.0    1300.2
```

Each is a command in its own rights, where missing or blank columns are implicitly zero.  Basically the first string is left-aligned, and all the others are right-aligned to the 20th, 30th, 40th,..., 80th column.  The first column is always an ID.  All the other columns are either IDs or floats.  Empty columns (either filled with spaces or nothing at all) are implicitly zero.

How might I go about parsing this?

I thought about:

```
grammar WeirdGrammar;
comm: KEYWORD NEWLINE
    | KEYWORD COLUMN NEWLINE
    | KEYWORD COLUMN COLUMN NEWLINE
    | KEYWORD COLUMN COLUMN COLUMN NEWLINE
    | KEYWORD COLUMN COLUMN COLUMN COLUMN NEWLINE
    | KEYWORD COLUMN COLUMN COLUMN COLUMN COLUMN NEWLINE
    | KEYWORD COLUMN COLUMN COLUMN COLUMN COLUMN COLUMN NEWLINE
    | KEYWORD COLUMN COLUMN COLUMN COLUMN COLUMN COLUMN COLUMN NEWLINE
    ;

KEYWORD: [A-Z] {getCharPositionInLine() == 1}? ([A-Z]|'-')* WS*? {getCharPositionInLine() == 10}? ;
COLUMN: .+? {(getCharPositionInLine() % 10) == 0}? ;
NEWLINE : '\r'? '\n' ;
WS : [ \t] ;
```

Basically the idea is to handle every combination of `KEYWORD` and `COLUMN` all the way from just a `KEYWORD` to a `KEYWORD` followed by 7 `COLUMN`s.  The `COLUMN` width limit of 10 each is enforced by nongreedily matching anything until the modulo of the CharPosition with 10 is zero.  The keyword is supposed to start at the beginning of the line, hence the first rule for that token, then it should extend no further than the 10th column, hence the second predicate.  Currently however this is not working, instead returning:

```
line 1:0 mismatched input 'ACOMAND          1' expecting KEYWORD
```

This still doesn't handle trailing whitespace, even in my naive implementation, but I suppose it will be a matter to impose no trailing white space.

Comment: 1) Does it matter to check that ACOMAND starts at column 1 and other values are aligned at a fixed position, else why not simply `ID VALUE* ?` 2) Please give all the necessary grammar so we can execute it. I have missing WS and `implicit definition of token`

Comment: 1)  Yes it does matter unfortunately, so I think I must use predicates to ensure correct alignment.  2) I have added the missing WS grammar now, my apologies for leaving it out.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Using ANTLR 4.6 and the given grammar and input, I have the following message :

```
line 3:0 no viable alternative at input 'ACOMAND    1.0    1.0\nACOMAND\nACOMAND  '
```

When debugging a grammar, it is very useful to list the tokens seen by the lexer :

```
$ echo $CLASSPATH
.:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.6-complete.jar
$ alias grun
alias grun='java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig'
$ grun Question question -tokens data.txt
[@0,0:9='ACOMAND   ',<KEYWORD>,1:0]
[@1,10:19='       1.0',<COLUMN>,1:10]
[@2,20:29='       1.0',<COLUMN>,1:20]
[@3,30:30='\n',<COLUMN>,1:30]
[@4,31:38='ACOMAND\n',<COLUMN>,2:0]
```

Before 4.6, tokens were displayed `[@3,30:30='\n',<n>,1:30]` and you had to look in the file  `-grammar-.tokens` which token has the number `n`. Now it is wonderfully translated, and you immediately see that the new-line character has been recognized as token `COLUMN`, not `NEWLINE` as you expected. This is because the lexer tries to match the input with each rule in sequence :

1. does `'\n'` match `[A-Z]` ? No, so it's not `KEYWORD`, next rule
2. does `'\n'` match `.+?` ? Yes, so it's a `COLUMN`, no chance to
   reach the `NEWLINE` rule.

So you need to put the `COLUMN` rule **after** the `NEWLINE` rule.

You also see that the second line of input has been tokenized as `[@4,31:38='ACOMAND\n',<COLUMN>,2:0]` because it cannot be matched by

```
KEYWORD: [A-Z] ... WS*?
```

because the rule requires white space and there is only a NL. Thus replace `WS*?` by `( WS* | NEWLINE )`.

Finally simplify redundant rules :

```
grammar Question;

question
    : KEYWORD COLUMN* NEWLINE
    ;

KEYWORD : [A-Z] {getCharPositionInLine() == 1}? ([A-Z]|'-')* ( WS* | NEWLINE ) {getCharPositionInLine() <= 10}? ;
NEWLINE : '\r'? '\n' ;
WS : [ \t] ;
COLUMN: .+? {(getCharPositionInLine() % 10) == 0}? ;
```

Now the lexer delivers :

```
[@0,0:9='ACOMAND   ',<KEYWORD>,1:0]
[@1,10:19='       1.0',<COLUMN>,1:10]
[@2,20:29='       1.0',<COLUMN>,1:20]
[@3,30:30='\n',<NEWLINE>,1:30]
[@4,31:38='ACOMAND\n',<KEYWORD>,2:0]
```

.

.

`2)` But is all this really useful ? Is a parser generator the right tool ? Delete one space and see what happens :

```
line 2:0 extraneous input 'ACOMAND\n' expecting {NEWLINE, COLUMN}
```

I think that you should leave the lexer do a simple job without these position constraints : create a token for non-blank data and eliminate the white space. Later in the parser or listener you can check the position : each token has properties like start, stop, line, etc.

Why not a Ruby script ? :-)

```
# Split 80 columns lines into 10 columns wide tokens, associate each token
# with its stop position in line (counting from 1) and an OK/WRONG flag
# if it is not aligned correctly.

tokens = Array.new

IO.readlines("data.txt").each_with_index do | line, i |
    if i == 0
    then
        puts "         #{line}"
        next
    end

    line_tokens = Array.new
    line = line.chomp # remove NL
    print "line #{i + 1} : "
    8.times.each do | n | # n = 0 to 7
        a = n * 10     # begin of split range counting from 0
        b = n * 10 + 9 # end of range
        token = line.slice(a..b)
        next if token.nil? || token.length == 0 # nil if edge case
        print token
        good_position = 'OK'
        position      = b + 1

        case n
        when 0 # first token must be at column 1
            good_position = 'WRONG' if token[0] == ' '
        else # other tokens must be right aligned in their 10 columns width field
            if token[-1] == ' ' && token != '          ' # not followed by NL
            then
                good_position = 'WRONG'
                unless (pos = token.rindex(' ')).nil?
                    position = position - 10 + pos - 1
                end
            end
            if token.length != 10 # last in line
            then
                good_position = 'WRONG'
                position = position - 10 + token.length
            end
        end

        line_tokens << [token.strip, position, good_position]
        break if b > line.length
    end
    puts # print a NL because print doesn't do it
    tokens << line_tokens
end

puts
puts "Lists of tokens : "
p tokens
```

Input data.txt :

```
....+....1....+....2....+....3....+....4....+....5....+....6....+....7....+....8
ACOMAND          1.0      1.0
ACOMAND
ACOMAND          1.0
ACOMAND          1.0       1.0    1300.2                .9       1.0
ACOMAND          1.0       1.0    1300.2                  .9
ACOMAND          OKK       1.0    1300.2                  .9       1.0       WOW
ACOMAND          1.0       1.0    1300.2
```

Output :

```
$ ruby -w split.rb 
         ....+....1....+....2....+....3....+....4....+....5....+....6....+....7....+....8
line 2 : ACOMAND          1.0      1.0
line 3 : ACOMAND
line 4 : ACOMAND          1.0
line 5 : ACOMAND          1.0       1.0    1300.2                .9       1.0
line 6 : ACOMAND          1.0       1.0    1300.2                  .9
line 7 : ACOMAND          OKK       1.0    1300.2                  .9       1.0       WOW
line 8 : ACOMAND          1.0       1.0    1300.2

Lists of tokens : 
[[["ACOMAND", 10, "OK"], ["1.0", 20, "OK"], ["1.0", 29, "WRONG"]], 
[["ACOMAND", 10, "OK"]], [["ACOMAND", 10, "OK"], ["1.0", 20, "OK"]], 
[["ACOMAND", 10, "OK"], ["1.0", 20, "OK"], ["1.0", 30, "OK"], ["1300.2", 
40, "OK"], ["", 50, "OK"], [".9", 58, "WRONG"], ["1.0", 68, "WRONG"]], 
[["ACOMAND", 10, "OK"], ["1.0", 20, "OK"], ["1.0", 30, "OK"], ["1300.2", 
40, "OK"], ["", 50, "OK"], [".9", 60, "OK"]], [["ACOMAND", 10, "OK"], 
["OKK", 20, "OK"], ["1.0", 30, "OK"], ["1300.2", 40, "OK"], ["", 50, 
"OK"], [".9", 60, "OK"], ["1.0", 70, "OK"], ["WOW", 80, "OK"]], 
[["ACOMAND", 10, "OK"], ["1.0", 20, "OK"], ["1.0", 30, "OK"], ["1300.2", 
40, "OK"]]]
```